# Is it possible to attain British Citizenship while abroad?

Tags: uk-citizenship

I am an EU citizen and my company is based in the UK. I was sent abroad on a long term assignment for 1 year. There's a rumor however that I might stay longer here, but nothing is decided.

I currently have ILR status, but I wonder in the case of my staying longer in this country (in Asia) if it is possible for me to do (outside of the UK):

1. Life in the UK test
2. Apply for and acquire UK citizenship - if I can do `1`.

I would be willing to fly in the UK to do 1. But obviously it is a hassle and if there's an alternative, I would prefer that.

I worked in UK for many years (2014 to 2022) it would be a shame if I lost the opportunity.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘somewhat’?

Comment: The Life in the UK test centres are only in the UK AFAIK. Note also that spending more than 450 days outside the UK during the 5 years before your application, and/or more than 90 days outside the UK in the last 12 months makes you inelegible https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-indefinite-leave-to-remain. You may also lose your ILR status if you’ve been away for extended periods eg more than 2 years at any time since you got it

Comment: I had ILR since before pandemic. Some of these points I don't think apply

Comment: It's something that you should definitely discuss with UK government. You really don't want any surprises there. You may be absolutely fine, or you might have trouble entering the UK again, that's something you should find out before you leave for too long.

Comment: Well I need a contact I suppose